# Can't connect to sites Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking

In my lab using Ubuntu 15.10,when accessing some official sites only one system get connect to that sites remaining systems not get connected to that sites. giving resolve error. But that same site working in Windows systems without any problem. I tried reinstall network manager but nothing sort of working my way...
any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

Check DNS settings on the machine. In Ubuntu open /etc/resolv.conf and add the following lines-

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and see if it works. The addresses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are google's public DNS servers. If you have your company's DNS servers you can use that instead.

Comment: We already using google's name servers only